# Signatures producing warning messages despite "no warnings qw(experimental::signatures)"

Tags: perl, moose

Created a package and wanted to use signatures.

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

use Moose;

has bar => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str' );

sub boom ($self, $stuff) {
    print "$stuff\n";
}
1;
```

Test it:

```
perl -wc Foo.pm
The signatures feature is experimental at ./Foo.pm line 11.
```

What's going on?  I thought the "no warnings" pragma would suppress that warning!

Comment: [use experimental](https://perldoc.perl.org/experimental), btw.

Comment: What Shawn is saying is that `use feature qw(signatures);` can be used in lieu of `use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);`

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `use experimental qw(signatures)` @ikegami ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the `use Moose;` line re-enables all warnings.

The fix is to move the `no warnings qw(experimental::signatures)` below the `use Moose;` line.

E.g.:

```
use Moose;
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);
```

Comment: `Mojo::Base` will do that too, along what a few other conveniences. Too bad `Moose` hides this feature in a code comment in its synopsis.